# Meteor HTTP.get result character encoding

Tags: encoding, meteor

I'm using HTTP.get to scrap pages from this [website](http://www.hurriyet.com.tr).

The result does not show Turkish characters. And I see things like:

> Copyright 2014 H�rriyet - Do�an Yay�n Holding

Is it possible to specify encoding when making this call? If so, how? If not, how else can I solve this issue?

Here is my code:

var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", postUrl, {options: {followRedirects:false}}).content

result contains these characters

Comment: how do you check that the encoding is correct? Have you checked that wherever you are seeing this output the encoding is set to utf-8? The request itself should be fine. If you are seeing this on a terminal, then make sure you have set the encoding of the terminal to utf-8 (unicode). If it's in another website, make sure your browser has the encoding set correctly, or set utf-8 in the head (meta tag).

Comment: I do have <meta charset="UTF-8"> in the head but that is not the issue. You can see my code. The result I get already has these characters. I think this is an open issue in Meteor, looking at: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/851

Comment: how do you determine that the result already contains these characters? where do you see them? in the server console I'm assuming right? Are you sure your server console supports unicode characters?

Comment: Yes I see it on the server console which does support unicode characters. And I save the result directly to mongodb and I see these these characters when I get it back from the db and post it on HTML. I found two fixes to this issue waiting to be merged on meteor git. I